# Mark up for .json file (in HTML)

Tags: json

How do I write out the fetch data syntax for this .json file?

```
{"Yoga":[
    {
        "StudioName":"Viva-Ki Yoga",
        "Address":"TODAYS HOURS: 11AM - 3PM",
        "Lat":"42.01560",
        "Long":"-87.99354"

    },
    {
        "StudioName":"Corepower",
        "Address":"TODAYS HOURS: 11AM - 3PM",
        "Lat":"39.83388",
        "Long":"-75.14502"

    },
    {
        "StudioName":"Bloom Yoga Studio",
        "Address":"TODAYS HOURS: 11AM - 3PM",
        "Lat":"41.955814",
        "Long":"-87.693292"

    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to put that in your HTML, you could do something like this. If this json is in a different file and you're requesting it, you'd need to use something like [jquery's $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/XMLHttpRequest)

```js
var json = document.querySelector("#myJSON").innerHTML;

try {
  json = JSON.parse(json);
  console.log(json);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

```html
<script type="application/json" id="myJSON">
{
    "Yoga": [
        {
            "StudioName": "Viva-Ki Yoga",
            "Address": "TODAYS HOURS: 11AM - 3PM",
            "Lat": "42.01560",
            "Long": "-87.99354"
        },
        {
            "StudioName": "Corepower",
            "Address": "TODAYS HOURS: 11AM - 3PM",
            "Lat": "39.83388",
            "Long": "-75.14502"
        },
        {
            "StudioName": "Bloom Yoga Studio",
            "Address": "TODAYS HOURS: 11AM - 3PM",
            "Lat": "41.955814",
            "Long": "-87.693292"
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, I would like to load the .json file from my html page using getJSON...but I'm not sure how to mark that up within the <script></script> tag.

Comment: <script>
   $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
});
</script>
<!-- I would like to link the above <script> to my .json file that outputs StudioName, Address, Latitude and Longtitude data on my HTML page -->

Comment: okay, well that's almost the same as $.ajax. There should be some examples at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/